# A way to convert anonymous Matlab function statements to c++?

Tags: c++, matlab, pointers

I am looking for a way to convert a Matlab routine that contains anonymous Matlab functions, to c++ using one single c++ function (i.e. without the need to define a function `phi` outside `func` and then pointing to its address inside `func`.

The prototype is: (the function pointer will be used as in/out parameter to define `phi`.)

```
void func(int index, double (*phi)(double,double)){
  if (index==1){
  // (..)
  }

};
```

The original Matlab function to convert is:

```
function [phi] = func(index)
  if (index==1)
     phi     = @(x,y) x + y;
  end
%(..)
end
```

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Are you asking about [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)? The function in the Matlab code returns something. The function in the C++ code doesn't.

Comment: I'm not sure if lambda expressions can be returned, but either way the c++ prototype was just a suggestion. The goal is to define/return 'phi' function according to the parameter 'index', exactly like the Matlab routine does, without any external function.

Comment: You can store a lambda expression in a `std::function` and return it.

Comment: Why “without any external function”? It’s easy to write a function that returns a function pointer. And it’s easy to define some additional functions in the same file, whose pointers you can return. Requiring no functions outside your function is a senseless limitation that is just going to make your work harder than it needs to be.

Comment: I changed the return type to std::function in order to return a lambda function and its works! Thanks a lot.